# Problems running three monitors with Loki

Tags: display, nvidia

Loki wasnt recognizing two of my montiors. I managed to fix that through installing the NVIDIA Driver for my card, but now those two monitors dont have a correct resolution and i cant set it up to be higher as 768p. Those two also get displayed as "Unknown display" in my System Settings -> Displays. They show up as DFP-0 and DFP-4 in nvidia-settings but my working one is showing up properly.

Comment: What graphics card and monitors are you using? Did you have this problem with Freya?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [xrandr](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding%20undetected%20resolutions) to define the monitor resolution.
That's what I did for my second monitor (using an Intel card and not Nvidia).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when using driver nvidia-304 after I installed the driver nvidia-361 the problem solved